# Create TypeAdapterFactory for data binding ObservableField

Tags: generics, kotlin, gson

I am using the ObservableField for data binding and I would like to deserialize with GSON.

```
class Foo: Observable {
   var bar: ObservableField<String>? = null
}
```

If I don't provide a TypeAdapter, GSON will try to deserialize as an object instead of a string.

My type adapter factory and type adapter:

```
class ObservableFieldTypeAdapterFactory: TypeAdapterFactory {
    override fun <T> create(gson: Gson, type: TypeToken<T>): TypeAdapter<T>? {
        if (type.rawType != ObservableField::class.java) {
            return null
        }

        return object : TypeAdapter<ObservableField<Any>>() {
            override fun read(reader: JsonReader): ObservableField<Any> {
              // get the generic type of the ObservableField and let GSON 
              // deserialize it
              val field = someDelegate.read(reader)
              // wrap it
              return ObservableField(field)
            }

            override fun write(out: JsonWriter?, value: ObservableField<Any>) {
                throw UnsupportedOperationException()
            }
        }.nullSafe() as TypeAdapter<T>
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to tell GSON to parse the generic type of the ObservableField:

```
// get the generic type of the ObservableField and let GSON deserialize it
val field = someDelegate.read(reader)
```

How to I delegate to GSON to parse the String field so I can wrap it?  I can check if it's a string field, but then this adapter doesn't support Ints or any generic object.

Do I need to check the type of field being read in with peek?  And then switch on every field type with the appropriate delete?

Comment: If the `Observable` implemented by `Foo` is from the databinding library as well, consider extending the `BaseObservable` and use all properties as normal types. You could use _Kotlin_ delegates or custom setter for notifying of the change.

Answer (score 0):

The `type` should actually implement `ParameterizedType` and you'd have to get the first element of `actualTypeArguments` to get the adapter for the generic type:

```
override fun <T> create(gson: Gson, type: TypeToken<T>): TypeAdapter<T>? {
    if (type.rawType != ObservableField::class.java) {
        return null
    }

    val paramType = (type as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0]
    return object : TypeAdapter<ObservableField<Any>>() {
        override fun read(reader: JsonReader): ObservableField<Any> {
          return ObservableField(gson.fromJson(reader, paramType))
        }

        override fun write(writer: JsonWriter, value: ObservableField<Any>) {
            gson.toJson(value.get(), paramType, writer)
        }
    }.nullSafe() as TypeAdapter<T>
}
```